# How to store token in Laravel 9 and Next js

Tags: reactjs, laravel, authentication, next.js, laravel-sanctum

I am using Laravel 9 with sanctum to build API and using Nextjs to build Front End.

https://github.com/laravel/breeze-next

Not using this.

After login, a token is generated. But how will I save that token to authenticate this user? I am not finding that information in Nextjs documentation.

Login in Laravel:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{

        /** @var User|null $user */
        $user = User::firstWhere('email', $request->email);

        if (!$user || !Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            return response()->json([
                'errors' => $validator,
                'message' => 'Email or Password is not correct!'
            ], 422);
        }

        $token = $user->createToken(config('app.name'))->plainTextToken;
        return response()->json([
            'errors'  => null,
            'token'   => 'Bearer ' . $token,
            'message' => 'Login Successful'
        ], 200);
}
```

Call login from Nextjs:

```
const login = async ({ ...props }) => {
    Axios
      .post("http://localhost:8000/api/login", props)
      .then((result) => {
        mutate()
        console.log("Successful");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response.status !== 422) throw error;
      });
  };
```

Calling the api/user

```
const { data: user, error, mutate } = useSWR('/api/user', () =>
        axios
            .get('/api/user')
            .then(res => res.data)
            .catch(error => {
                if (error.response.status !== 409) throw error

                router.push('/verify-email')
            }),
    )
```

But this needs a token.

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You need to store the token on the client, [here is an example article](https://dev.to/nilanth/how-to-secure-jwt-in-a-single-page-application-cko) that discusses how and where but there [many more](https://www.google.com/search?q=where+to+store+jwt+token+react).

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you're trying to store the token in the frontend.

You can try something like [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

```
localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
```

Something like this can do it.

Calling it would be something like this:

```
const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    axios
        .get("/api/endpoint/", {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Authorization: "Bearer " + token
            }
        })
        .then(response => (this.result = response.data));
}
```

Hope this helps.